# Angular Material nested accordion template gets picked up my the parent accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-accordion` nested within another accordion, and I want to render the content of the parent accordion directly, but lazy load the child accordion. Angular Material provisions for lazy loading by wrapping the accordion content in an ng-template annotated with the `matExpansionPanelContent` directive.

My code looks like this:

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel 1
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div class="panel-content">

      Immediately loaded parent content

      <mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            Panel 1A
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
            Lazy-loaded child content
          </ng-template>

        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            Panel 1B
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
            Lazy-loaded child content
          </ng-template>

        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel 2
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div class="panel-content">
      Immediated loaded parent content
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

What happens instead is that the parent accordion *and* the child accordion pick up and render the lazy-loaded content, so it gets rendered twice.

Is there a way to pass the lazy-loaded content directly to a panel, so that only that specific panel renders the content? Or a better way I can do this?

Answer (score 4):

Initially I used a work around which was to lazy-load both parent and child content, but this was not ideal as the lazy-loading of the parent content resulted in some behaviour that I didn't want.

It is in fact better to add an empty `MatExpansionPanelContent` template to the parent panel.

To understand what is going on, I looked through the source code and saw that they are just using a `ContentChild` decorator to select the template:

```js
@ContentChild(MatExpansionPanelContent) _lazyContent: MatExpansionPanelContent;
```

This selects the *first* template with the `MatExpansionPanelContent` directive applied that it comes across within its scope. Adding an empty one satisfies the parent's search for a `ContentChild` so it stops looking and does not find the child template.

Here is the code:

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      Panel 1
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <!-- Added empty template -->
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent></ng-template>

    <!-- Rest of the parent content is eagerly-loaded -->
    <div class="panel-content">
      Immediately loaded parent content

      <mat-accordion displayMode="flat">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            Panel 1A
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
            Lazy-loaded child content
          </ng-template>

        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful! The empty templated worked like a charm.